# Serial communication in Linux user space (non blocking)

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, multiprocessing, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to get an arduino board communicate with a beaglebone ( BB) white running Ubuntu using UART. I have read that the BB uart driver is already interrupt driven.

I want to store all incoming data into a sort of buffer which I can read when required, similar to the way it's done in microcontrollers. But I'm trying to avoid kernel programming so I won't be able to use the driver's data structures. I'm looking for a complete user space solution.

I'm planning to use two python processes, one to write all incoming data (to a shared list) and the other to read it as required so that the read is non blocking.

I have two questions:

1. Is this the right approach? if yes, please suggest a simple interprocess communication method that will suffice.
2. What is the right way to implement this?

Note: I'm using the PyBBIO library that reads and writes directly to the /dev/mem special file.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  To be clear, you are trying to develop RS-232 serial port communications on the Beaglebone, which already has the Linux operating system?  If so then you need to realize that there's a serial port driver in the kernel, and you have to execute your application in userspace.  The kernel will buffer all input and output between your program and the driver. *"write all incoming data"* is an oxymoron; do you mean "store the incoming data"?.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... 
Yes, I'm trying to setup a RS 232 serial port communication on BB and I'm aware that there is already an interrupt driven UART driver.

Comment: What I essentially need is a mechanism to read the kernel buffer in a non-blocking fashion. 
One of the solutions I could think of is a userspace buffer (or stack/ list sort of datastructure) which mirrors the driver's buffer, which I can read (by popping or using index).
I wanted to know if this approach is correct? And if it is, how can it be implemented in python?

Comment: Sorry again, I figured out that I can open the /dev/mem file with the NONBLOCK param (handle the exception when there's no data to read) and access UART registers using mmap() directly. So a user space buffer is just not required.

Comment: *"I can open the /dev/mem file ... and access UART registers...directly."* -- You're trying to circumvent the OS, which means you might as well get rid of Linux and go bare metal.  When you have a secure OS like Linux, you shouldn't be trying to do *"similar to the way it's done in microcontrollers"*, which is rarely structured and not portable.  You probably don't even need non-blocking reads, since multi-threading or **select()** are available.  **Actually your question seems to be a XY problem.**.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/), which  uses the kernel interfaces (I don't know what PyBBIO does). It provides automatic input buffering - so you don't need an extra process. If you do want to have more processes use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). A simpler alternative is [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), which saves you the communication part. For multiprocessing with network support use [Ipython's cluster](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking at pyserial API.